# Are the Cluster Leader and Cluster Singleton node the same

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

Is the cluster leader and node cluster singletons start on, the same node in Akka?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. The leader role can change during gossip convergence as a routine part of cluster operations when nodes join, leave, or lose connection (among other reasons). See the [Specification](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/common/cluster.html#Leader) for more information.

Specifically, note:

> The role of the leader is to shift members in and out of the cluster, changing joining members to the up state or exiting members to the removed state

So it isn't comparable to a Primary-Secondary style of HA system where a node takes all of the load, and fails over to a secondary when the Primary dies. Actor singletons could be placed on any node, and that node can go in and out of the leader role as time passes.